# how to login to a chrome browser in ubuntu via console

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I have managed to install a chrome onto the ubuntu. I wonder how can I login to my chrome browser via console so  I can trigger the remote desktop add-on practically remote desktop using chrome remote desktop extension

Comment: you can launch chrome from the terminal using `google-chrome`. If you're doing this remotely (over SSH) the use `export DISPLAY=:0` before it